# Non-Recursive get_term_children()

Tags: taxonomy, terms

I have a custom taxonomy called `product_category`. There are child terms 3 levels down.

They look like this:

```
Term1
    Term2
        Term3
```

When I am on the taxonomy page for Term1, I wish to use `get_term_children()` to retrieve Term2, without retrieving Term3.

If that makes sense...

Can this be achieved with get_term_children() or is there another function I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you want to output term data, so you can use `get_terms` with the `child_of` argument, then iterate over returned terms and check that the parent of each term is your main term id:

```
$parent_id = 42;
$children = get_terms( 'product_category', array( 'child_of' => $parent_id ) );

foreach( $children as $child ) {
    if( $parent_id == $child->parent )
        echo $child->name;
}
```

This will exclude grandchildren, as their parent term ID will be a child term, not your top level term.

Comment: That did the trick alright, thanks very much Milo. Perfect.

Comment: I need 3 more reputation to vote you up I'm afraid!

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use `child_of` instead of `parent`?

Comment: @Schism you're right, `parent` would be the simpler method!